# Local time as a measurable map from Wiener space

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

Let $B$ be a Brownian motion on $[0,1]$. The local time of $B$, which I will denote by $L$, is defined as the process on $\mathbb R$ such that
$$\int_0^1 F(B_t)~dt=\int_\mathbb R F(x)L(x)~dx,\qquad\forall F\text{ measurable},$$
or equivalently
$$L(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac1{2\epsilon}\int_0^1\mathbf 1\{B(t)\in(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)\}~dt.$$

A well-known property of $L$ is that, almost surely, $x\mapsto L(x)$ is a continuous and compactly supported function. Thus, one may be tempted to think of $L$ as a random variable taking values in the space $C_0(\mathbb R)$ of continuous functions with compact support.

> **Question.** Is there a natural topology $\tau$ (such as uniform convergence on compacts) on $C_0(\mathbb R)$ with respect to which we can actually realize $L$ time as a measurable map from some probability space to $\big(C_0(\mathbb R),\mathcal B_\tau\big)$, where $\mathcal B_\tau$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

A natural choice here would be to choose this probability space as the continuous functions $C[0,1]$ with the uniform convergence topology and the Wiener measure, but I've never seen such a construction in any work treating local time. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: If you use the sup norm topology on $C_0(\mathbb{R})$ then I think this should be more or less immediate, since the Borel $\sigma$-algebra of that topology is generated by the evaluation maps.  I am not so sure about the topology of uniform convergence on compacts - in particular, I don't know offhand whether its Borel $\sigma$-algebra is standard Borel.

Comment: I don't think it will matter what you choose as the underlying probability space, because everything is going to come from the fact that $B(t)$ is a Brownian motion.  The canonical Wiener space will do just fine, though.

Comment: @NateEldredge Thanks for your comment; you're right this amounts to a complete triviality. I really should brush up on my elementary measure theory!